# Volley JsonObjectRequest Error response

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonresponse

I've got class with simple Json Object Request, this is method where whole request is called, and in LogCat I get only:

```
Volley: [2] 2.onErrorResponse: Error:
```

so I don't know where to look for a fix

```
private void getBeerDetails() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/13",
                    null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        beerName.setText(response.getString("name"));
                        alc.setText(response.getString("abv"));
                        ibu.setText(response.getString("ibu"));
                        firstBrewed.setText(response.getString("first_brewed"));
                        yeast.setText(response.getString("yeast"));
                        description.setText(response.getString("description"));
                        foodPairing.setText(response.getString("food_pairing"));

                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(response.getString("image_url"))
                                .into(beerImageView);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Error:", error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: show your complete log cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***As I see here your response is in JsonArray format.
So try with below***

```
private void getBeerDetails() {
    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest 
            (Request.Method.GET,
                    "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/13",
                    null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                       if(response.length()>0){
                           //make a loop and add item to your list
                           }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Error:", error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: Yes, response is an array, but this is array of values of one single item, there is no list, It's beer name, description, image url and so on. This is single activity showing all data

Comment: ok, it works, but it's very unintuitive to have to load single object data with array, but thank You for help

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is not very descriptive. However, I think you need to set the `content-type` to `application/json` in the header for your GET request. Override the `getHeaders` function while creating the request. Here's a java example.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonBody,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("TAG", error.getMessage(), error);
        }
    }){

    @Override 
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();                
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return params; 
    } 
};
```

**Update**

As per your comment in the answer, you have failed to parse the JSON which was returned from your GET request. As I have seen from your response JSON, you are receiving an array of objects. I would like to suggest using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for JSON parsing. Its simple and easier to implement. You need to define a class containing the fields of the object in your array which is returned in your response. Then just use Gson to convert the values from JSON array into the array of that specific object that you have created. Here's a sample.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data[] dataArray = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Data[].class);
```

Comment: Ok, with error message that I get with this code I can see that I was trying to parse son array with only one object and with no name I guess (this is my first time experience with parsing json requests). I thought it is object https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/13 but how to parse it otherwise?

Comment: I understand, I will definitely look deeper in that Gson, Thank You